# Is there an easy way to enter texttt mode, like $ for math mode?

Tags: typewriter

When I want to refer to a math variable, say some index `i`, I simply surround it with dollars (i.e., `$i$`) as opposed to writing `\begin{math}i\end{math}`.

Is there some similar option for `texttt` mode, e.g. `§i§`, to replace `\texttt{i}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Many editors have shortcuts for these commands, so it might be an idea to explore those.

Comment: @gail Instead of looking for a LaTeX solution, which may be somewhat risky as emphasized by David below, why not program your editor so that the typing of `\texttt[]` is made easy?

Comment: When I need to type a lot of `\texttt` in a part of the document I usually just copy `\texttt{` to the clipboard and use CTRL-V to enter it quickly (and manually add `}` afterwards).

Comment: @Denis because a main point of using something like LaTeX instead of WYSIWIG software is that it allows us to avoid such hacks? If you need something often, the best way is _not_ to let the editor duplicate it lots of times (cluttering your source and making it difficult to change styling later on), but instead define a macro once and for all and let the _compiler_ expand it.

Comment: I would also remark that lots of people use `\texttt` when really they should be using `\verb` instead. I would therefore recommend [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559248/5905).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `§` as a delimiter without affecting other characters using the same first byte.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{§}{\makeabbreviationtt}
\def\makeabbreviationtt#1§{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

This is §monospaced§. This doesn't affect ©, ¶
and other similar UTF-8 characters.

You can also do §¶§

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Not for `\texttt` but for `\verb` the base distribution includes `shortvrb` package that allows you to define a shorthand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb|


\begin{document}
  aaaa |z|  aaa
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def§#1§{\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
roman §tt text§ back to roman
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as David points out in the comments, because `§` is not a single byte character, but a UTF-8 extended (multi-byte) character, this approach will wipe out any of the UTF-8 characters that begin with the same prefix, resulting in an error, if those characters are used (such as `©`).

So, if you wanted this type of solution it would be better to choose the delimiter as a single-byte ASCII character and making it active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`|=\active
\def|#1|{\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
roman |tt text| back to roman
\end{document}
```

The downside here is you lose the use of `|` as a normal input character. Therefore, you could get fancy and build an escape into the definition, so that `||` together would echo a single `|` to be typeset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\svvert|
\catcode`|=\active
\def|#1|{\ifx\relax#1\relax\expandafter\svvert\else\texttt{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
roman |tt text| back to roman || or $y =||x||$ and |then back to texttt|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure that's a good idea (you just redefined an entire range of characters sharing the same utf-8 prefix)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wasn't sure it was a good idea, and now I'm even more sure it is not.  However, it is what the OP asked for.

Comment: No the OP didn't ask that a whole block of characters were made unusable, try adding  © to your text:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Point taken

Comment: the comment about `\long` is also wrong, as `\texttt` is not `\long` so you would still get an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are a fount of knowledge.

Comment: Rather than the escape approach, since `|` really only makes sense in math mode, you could use `\ifmathmode` to check for math mode and emit the appropriate character, and if not call a helper macro to do the consumption of everything up to the next `|` and set it in `\texttt`.

Comment: @DonHosek Yes, thank you, that is correct.  The thought crossed my mind earlier, but I didn't pursue it.